# How to import and use npm packages in background.ts of chrome extension built using angular 10

Tags: angular, webpack, google-chrome-extension, angular10

I am creating a google chrome extension using angular 10. Is it possible to import npm package in background.ts (after transpilation background.js). If yes, then how can we import it and bundle it, so that it can be added in manifest.json file.

I am using **@angular-builders/custom-webpack** package to convert background.ts to background.js via webpack.

**custom.webpack.config.js**

```
const CopyWebPackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        new CopyWebPackPlugin({
            patterns:[
            {from:'manifest.json', to:''}            
            ]
        }),
      ],    
   entry: { background: 'src/background.ts' }    
}
```

**angular.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "testproject": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
          "options": {
            "customWebpackConfig": {
              "path": "./custom.webpack.config.js"
            },
            "outputPath": "dist/testproject",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            .............
            .............
```

**Manifest.json**

```
{
    "name": "Great Extension",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Build an Extension with Angular",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "browser_action": {
        "default_popup": "index.html#/home"
    },
    "key": <chrome extension key>,
    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "./background.js",
            "./runtime.js"          
        ]
    },
    "permissions": [
        "identity"
    ]
}
```

**Note:** runtime.js gets created on building angular project using **ng build** command

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, I resolved it by adding background.ts in files in tsconfig.app.json

```
{
  ...
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts",
    "src/background.ts"
  ],
  ...
}
```